# Преобразовать последовательность, добавив к ней наименьшее число символов

Tags: массивы, pascal

Есть программа. Нужно сделать ввод элементов 3 способами:

1. Массив X заполняется путем ввода данных с клавиатуры: из предопределенного файла Input;
2. Массив X заполняется с использованием генератора равномерно-распределенных чисел;
3. Массив X заполняется с использованием типизированной константы-массив;

**Пока есть такой вариант программы (1 вариант)**

```
var
 a,w:string[255];
 i,j,k,n,p,x:integer; 
 t,b:boolean; 
begin 
 readln(a); 
 n:=length(a); 
 t:=true; 
 k:=n; 
 p:=0;
 i:=1; 
 while (i<n) and t do 
  begin 
   i:=p+1; 
   if a[i]=a[n] 
    then 
     begin
      j:=1; 
      b:=true; 
      x:=(n+1-i) div 2; 
      while (j<x) and b do 
       begin 
        if a[i+j]<>a[n-j] 
         then 
          b:=false; 
        inc(j); 
       end; 
      if b 
       then 
        t:=false 
       else 
        inc(p); 
      end 
    else 
     inc(p); 
  end; 
 writeln(p);
 w:=''; 
 for i:=1 to p do 
  w:=a[i]+w; 
 w:=a+w; 
 writeln(w);      
 readln; 
end.
```

Comment: Сессия скоро? )

Comment: язык программирования какой? Паскаль?